# Close Scanner when entering "0"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writting a program where the user enters a String input and the program finds the number of words and the number of int numbers. Scanner should close when the user enters "0".

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunMe
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  input = in.nextLine();
    Counter numbers = new Counter();
    Counter words = new Counter();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s");

    while(s.nextInt() != 0)
    {
        if(s.hasNextInt())
        {
            numbers.add();
        }
        else
        {
            words.add();
        }
    }

    s.close();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Number of numbers : " + numbers.value());
    System.out.println("Number of words : " + words.value());

}
}
```

and the class Counter

```
public class Counter
{
    private int value;

    public int add()
    {
        value++;
        return value;
    }
    public int value()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

When I run my program I get the following excepion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at RunMe.main(RunMe.java:13)
```

Comment: Can you please include a sample input in your post as well?.

Comment: s.nextInt() will only read in a number and not a string(word).  When you try to enter a word s.nextInt() will give you InputMismatchException because it's expecting a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Scanner the console input must be feed using "enter". To avoid this, some other native library would be required, such as [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net). There are other options in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089546/how-to-write-an-equivalent-of-keylistener-with-jline).

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Change the condition of your main loop to check if there is something to read and use a break if the numeral is equals to 0.

---

### Solution

```
while(s.hasNext())
{
    if(s.hasNextInt())
    {
        if (s.nextInt() == 0) break;
        numbers.add();
    }
    else
    {
        s.next();
        words.add();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice way of checking if the input is an int or not!

Comment: @Yan Thank you. That's nice :)

Comment: Scanner still doesn't close when entering 0. I have to click "enter" to calculate the number of words and numbers

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou Do you mean that you don't want an "enter" click (i.e., immediately calculate the number of words and numbers while user press "0")?

Comment: @Tsung-TingKuo exactly! Is it possible?

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou I just posted another answer for your reference :-)